# JS Slider add autoplay, stop and play buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm writting a javascript slider and I want the slider to autoplay.

The problem with my code is that the autoplay only works partially, because it slides only to the second slide. How to make the slider autoplay through all the slides?

Also I would like to do a stop/play button for the slider to be more wcag friendly but I don't know how to do it, any ideas?

Can you help me?

```js
const slider = (function () {

    //const
    const slider = document.getElementById("slider"); // main wrapper
    console.log(slider);
    const sliderContent = document.querySelector(".slider-content"); // wrapper for container slides and controls
    console.log(sliderContent);
    const sliderWrapper = document.querySelector(".slider-content-wrapper"); // slide container
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-content__item"); // slide wrapper
    const sliderContentControls = createHTMLElement("div", "slider-content__controls"); // control block inside sliderContent
    let dotsWrapper = null; // Dots wrapper
    let prevButton = null; // Buttons
    let nextButton = null;

    let leftArrow = null; // Arrows
    let rightArrow = null;
    let intervalId = null; // set Interval ID

    // data
    const itemsInfo = {
        offset: 0, // offset of the container with slides relative to the starting point (first slide)
        position: {
            current: 0, // current slide number
            min: 0, // first slide
            max: elements.length - 1 // last slide
        },
        intervalSpeed: 1000, // Auto slide speed

        update: function (value) {
            this.position.current = value;
            this.offset = -value;
        },
        reset: function () {
            this.position.current = 0;
            this.offset = 0;
        }
    };

    const controlsInfo = {
        buttonsEnabled: false,
        dotsEnabled: false,
        prevButtonDisabled: true,
        nextButtonDisabled: false
    };

    // Slider initialization
    function init(props) {
        // let {buttonsEnabled, dotsEnabled} = controlsInfo;
        let { intervalSpeed, position, offset } = itemsInfo;

        // Check for Markup Elements
        if (slider && sliderContent && sliderWrapper && elements) {
            // Validation of input parameters
            if (props && props.intervalSpeed) {
                intervalSpeed = props.intervalSpeed;
            }
            if (props && props.currentItem) {
                if (parseInt(props.currentItem) >= position.min && parseInt(props.currentItem) <= position.max) {
                    position.current = props.currentItem;
                    offset = - props.currentItem;
                }
            }
            if (props && props.buttons) {
                controlsInfo.buttonsEnabled = true;
            }
            if (props && props.dots) {
                controlsInfo.dotsEnabled = true;
            }

            _updateControlsInfo();
            _createControls(controlsInfo.dotsEnabled, controlsInfo.buttonsEnabled);
            _render();

            // Start autoplay
            intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                const nextSlide = itemsInfo.position.current + 1;
                if (nextSlide > itemsInfo.position.max) {
                    updateItemsInfo(itemsInfo.position.min);
                } else {
                    updateItemsInfo(nextSlide);
                }
            }, intervalSpeed);
        } else {
            console.log("The slider layout is incorrect. Check for all required classes 'slider/slider-content/slider-wrapper/slider-content__item''");
        }
    }


    // Update control properties
    function _updateControlsInfo() {
        const { current, min, max } = itemsInfo.position;
        controlsInfo.prevButtonDisabled = current > min ? false : true;
        controlsInfo.nextButtonDisabled = current < max ? false : true;
    }

    // Creat Markup Elements
    function _createControls(dots = false, buttons = false) {

        // Wrapper for controls
        sliderContent.append(sliderContentControls);

        // Controls
        createArrows();
        dots ? createDots() : null;

        // Arrows function
        function createArrows() {
            const dValueLeftArrow = "M31.7 239l136-136c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L127.9 256l96.4 96.4c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L201.7 409c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-136-136c-9.5-9.4-9.5-24.6-.1-34z";
            const dValueRightArrow = "M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34z";
            const leftArrowSVG = createSVG(dValueLeftArrow);
            const rightArrowSVG = createSVG(dValueRightArrow);

            leftArrow = createHTMLElement("div", "prev-arrow");
            leftArrow.append(leftArrowSVG);
            leftArrow.addEventListener("click", () => updateItemsInfo(itemsInfo.position.current - 1))

            rightArrow = createHTMLElement("div", "next-arrow");
            rightArrow.append(rightArrowSVG);
            rightArrow.addEventListener("click", () => updateItemsInfo(itemsInfo.position.current + 1))

            sliderContentControls.append(leftArrow, rightArrow);

            // SVG function
            function createSVG(dValue, color = "currentColor") {
                const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
                svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 256 512");
                const path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
                path.setAttribute("fill", color);
                path.setAttribute("d", dValue);
                svg.appendChild(path);
                return svg;
            }
        }

        // Dots function
        function createDots() {
            dotsWrapper = createHTMLElement("div", "dots");
            for (let i = 0; i < itemsInfo.position.max + 1; i++) {
                const dot = document.createElement("div");
                dot.className = "dot";
                dot.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    updateItemsInfo(i);
                })
                dotsWrapper.append(dot);
            }
            sliderContentControls.append(dotsWrapper);
        }

    }

    // Set class for controls (buttons, arrows)
    function setClass(options) {
        if (options) {
            options.forEach(({ element, className, disabled }) => {
                if (element) {
                    disabled ? element.classList.add(className) : element.classList.remove(className)
                } else {
                    console.log("Error: function setClass(): element = ", element);
                }
            })
        }
    }

    // Update Slider Values
    function updateItemsInfo(value) {
        itemsInfo.update(value);
        _slideItem(true);
    }

    // Show Items
    function _render() {
        const { prevButtonDisabled, nextButtonDisabled } = controlsInfo;
        let controlsArray = [
            { element: leftArrow, className: "d-none", disabled: prevButtonDisabled },
            { element: rightArrow, className: "d-none", disabled: nextButtonDisabled }
        ];
        if (controlsInfo.buttonsEnabled) {
            controlsArray = [
                ...controlsArray,
                { element: prevButton, className: "disabled", disabled: prevButtonDisabled },
                { element: nextButton, className: "disabled", disabled: nextButtonDisabled }
            ];
        }

        // Show/Hide Controls
        setClass(controlsArray);

        // Moving the slider
        sliderWrapper.style.transform = `translateX(${itemsInfo.offset * 100}%)`;

        // Set active element for points (dot)
        if (controlsInfo.dotsEnabled) {
            if (document.querySelector(".dot--active")) {
                document.querySelector(".dot--active").classList.remove("dot--active");
            }
            dotsWrapper.children[itemsInfo.position.current].classList.add("dot--active");
        }
    }

    // Move slide
    function _slideItem(autoMode = false) {
        if (autoMode && intervalId) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        _updateControlsInfo();
        _render();
    }

    // Create HTML markup for an element
    function createHTMLElement(tagName = "div", className, innerHTML) {
        const element = document.createElement(tagName);
        className ? element.className = className : null;
        innerHTML ? element.innerHTML = innerHTML : null;
        return element;
    }

    // Available Methods
    return { init };
}())

slider.init({
    // intervalSpeed: 1000,
    currentItem: 0,
    buttons: true,
    dots: true
});
```

```css
.slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*Window with slides*/
.slider-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Container for slides (move) */
.slider-content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/*Slide*/
.slider-content__item {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.image-1 {
    background-color: #963484;
}

.image-2 {
    background-color: #3066BE;
}

.image-3 {
    background-color: #60AFFF;
}

.image-4 {
    background-color: #28C2FF;
}

.image-5 {
    background-color: #2AF5FF;
}

.image-6 {
    background-color: navy;
}


/* Block with controls */
.slider-controls {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Block with controls inside the window */
.slider-content__controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    /*transform: translateY(-50%);*/
    /*padding:0 15px;*/
}

/* Arrows */
.prev-arrow,
.next-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.prev-arrow {
    left: 20px;
}

.next-arrow {
    right: 20px;
}

.prev-arrow:hover,
.next-arrow:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

/* Dots */
.dots {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 10%;
}

.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.dot:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.dot:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.dot--active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

/* Buttons */
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 8px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #3066BE;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

button:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #60AFFF;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* Mods */
.disabled {
    background-color: #DCCFCF;
    color: #B0A8A8;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.d-none {
    display: none;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.centered {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slider">
    <div class="slider-content">
        <div class="slider-content-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-content__item image-1">1</div>
            <div class="slider-content__item image-2">2</div>
            <div class="slider-content__item image-3">3</div>
            <div class="slider-content__item image-4">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies within your internal function _slideItem.
You are clearing the interval and never setting it again, this function is called when the slide changes by button or auto play.
After commenting out the clearInterval line you can see that the autoplay works as you expect.

```
function _slideItem(autoMode = false) {
    if (autoMode && intervalId) {
        /* clearInterval(intervalId) */;
    }
    _updateControlsInfo();
    _render();
}
```